# Ironpython in visual studio 2019

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ironpython, ironpython-studio

I have been struggling to create a button that loads the file using IronPython in Visual studio 2019. The console window pops up for 1 sec and disappears.

[image]

```
import wpf

clr.AddReference('IronPython.Wpf') #Add a reference for the ' System.Windows.Forms' namespace and etc..
clr.AddReference('System.IO')
clr.AddReference('Systemm.Drawing')
clr.AddReference('System.Reflection')
clr.AddReference('System.Threading')
clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')

class MyWindow(Window):

    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication1.xaml')
        
    def Button_Click(self, sender, e):
         #Folder path of variables
        FOLDER_PATH = r'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\waveform1' #Back slash will be treated as escape character
        # Define a funhction to print out the file name
        # Input parameter will be dir
    def listDir(dir):
        fileNames = os.listdir(dir)
        for fileName in fileNames:
            print('File Name: ' +fileName)
            print('Folder Path: ' + os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir,fileName)))

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

Comment: Can you please at least use a proper screenshot instead of a tilted photo of your physical screen? Or better yet, just copy and paste the error message **text**.

Comment: Why is `if __name__ == '__main__':` inside `class MyWindow`? Is that on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `if __name__ == '__main__':` outside off your class

```
import wpf
clr.AddReference('IronPython.Wpf') #Add a reference for the ' System.Windows.Forms' namespace and etc..
clr.AddReference('System.IO')
clr.AddReference('Systemm.Drawing')
clr.AddReference('System.Reflection')
clr.AddReference('System.Threading')
clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')

class MyWindow(Window):

    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication1.xaml')
        
    def Button_Click(self, sender, e):
            #Folder path of variables
        FOLDER_PATH = r'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\waveform1' #Back slash will be treated as escape character
        # Define a funhction to print out the file name
        # Input parameter will be dir
    def listDir(dir):
        fileNames = os.listdir(dir)
        for fileName in fileNames:
            print('File Name: ' +fileName)
            print('Folder Path: ' + os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir,fileName)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

**I give Some example**

```
import wpf

import FlippingGame

from System.Windows import Application, Window, Visibility
from System.Windows.Media import Brushes

class WpfSampleWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'PyWpfSample.xaml')
        self.game = FlippingGame.FlippingGame()
    
    def flipButton_Click(self, sender, e):
        wager = self._getWager()
        if not wager:
            return

        guess = "H" if self.guessHeadsButton.IsChecked else "T"
        won, toss = self.game.flip(guess, wager)

        self._showToss(won, toss)
        self._showBankroll()
        self._maybeEndGame()
    
    def Window_Loaded(self, sender, e):
        self._showBankroll()

    def _getWager(self):
        try:
            wager = int(self.wagerBox.Text)
        except ValueError as v:
            self.wagerBox.Foreground = Brushes.Red
            self._showError("Wager must be a number.")
            return
        else:
            self._hideError()
            self.wagerBox.Foreground = Brushes.Black

        if wager < 1:
            self.wagerBox.Foreground = Brushes.Red
            self._showError("Wager must be at least 1 credit.")
            return

        if wager > self.game.bankroll:
            self.wagerBox.Foreground = Brushes.Red
            self._showError("Wager cannot be more than your bankroll.")
            return

        return wager
    
    def _showError(self, error):
        self.errorLabel.Content = error
        self.errorLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible

    def _hideError(self):
        self.errorLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed

    def _showToss(self, won, toss):
        self.resultLabel.Content = toss
        self.resultLabel.Foreground = Brushes.Green if won else Brushes.Red

    def _showBankroll(self):
        self.bankrollLabel.Content = str(self.game.bankroll)

    def _maybeEndGame(self):
        if self.game.bankroll <= 0:
            self._showToss(False, 'X')

            self.flipButton.IsEnabled = False
            self.wagerBox.IsEnabled = False
            self.guessHeadsButton.IsEnabled = False
            self.guessTailsButton.IsEnabled = False
    
    def wagerBox_GotFocus(self, sender, e):
        sender.Foreground = Brushes.Black

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(WpfSampleWindow())
```

Comment: it still shows the message: The progress' [2532] ipwy32.exe has exited with code 1

Comment: can you elaborate more on that, please?

Comment: Where you get `Window` object you not import it